# WIndows Authentication On Java Swing Program

Tags: java, windows, swing, authentication

Right now, I'm creating a GUI app using Swing which requires the user to log in. I've created my own login dialog with its mechanism. But, An idea crossed my mind. It would be easier if i use Windows login dialog (Like what I'm seeing in eBay)

[EBay asks an Authentication from Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVjTZ.png)

I've tried to use Advapi32.INSTANCE.LogonUser but it doesn't work. Below is the Code

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;

public class PINLogin {
    public static boolean authenticateUser() {
        WinNT.HANDLEByReference hProcess = new WinNT.HANDLEByReference();
        WinNT.HANDLEByReference hThread = new WinNT.HANDLEByReference();
        boolean success = false;

        // Set up the startup info structure for the new process
        WinBase.STARTUPINFO startupInfo = new WinBase.STARTUPINFO();
        startupInfo.cb = new WinDef.DWORD(startupInfo.size());
        startupInfo.lpDesktop = "WinSta0\\Default";

        // Create the new process with the "runas" verb to show the Windows login dialog
        success = Advapi32.INSTANCE.CreateProcessWithLogonW("",
                                                             "Administrator",
                                                             "password",
                                                             Advapi32.LOGON_WITH_PROFILE,
                                                             null,
                                                             "cmd.exe /c echo Hello, world!",
                                                             WinBase.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                                                             null,
                                                             null,
                                                             startupInfo,
                                                             new WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION());
        if (success) {
            // Wait for the process to exit
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.WaitForSingleObject(hProcess.getValue(), WinBase.INFINITE);
            // GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess.getValue(), new WinDef.DWORDByReference()).getValue()
            if ( Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess.getValue(), new IntByReference())){
                success = true;
            } else {
                success = false;
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (authenticateUser()) {
            // User authenticated successfully
            System.out.println("User authenticated successfully");
        } else {
            // Authentication failed
            System.out.println("Authentication failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of application, command line, gui, web?

Comment: @aled GUI, Using Swing

Comment: I've not tried it but this project might help: https://github.com/Waffle/waffle

Comment: @Guillaume not that one, i mean a windows login dialog (you can see it by opening Password Manager on chrome and it will ask windows PIN)